# How to fix Python restarting whenever I start program on IDLE environment?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

```
import random

winning_conditon = 0
no_of_guesses = 0
comp_guess = random.randint(1,100)

while (no_of_guesses == 11) or (winning_conditon == 1):
    user_guess = int(input("What is your guess? "))
    if user_guess < 1 or user_guess > 100:
        print("Your number is invalid!")

    elif comp_guess == user_guess:
        print("Well Done!")
        winning_condition = 1
    elif comp_guess < user_guess:
        print("Your number is too high!")
    elif comp_guess > user_guess:
        print("Your number is too low!")

    no_of_guesses = no_of_guesses + 1
    print(no_of_guesses)
print("You haven't guessed the right amount of times or u won.")
```

Whenever I start python IDLE (i am using Portable Python 3.2.5.1 (http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython3.2.5.1/)) it comes up with a restart message and then it displays an "=" sign and doesn't continue the program. Do you know a fix?

Comment: Is this at all related to the code you've posted?

Comment: With the initial indent removed, the program runs.  The RESTART line is normal when you run from IDLE editor.  That means that the program is running in a fresh namespace, about the same as if you ran from a command line.  Since the while condition is false, the loop is never run.  You need the `not` as in User's answer.  The last line is printed and the program quits.  What I see after the printed line is `>>> `, also as in User's answer.  You would see the same output if you ran `python -i <filename>` in a console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your program I get this output:

```
Python 3.2.5 (default, May 15 2013, 23:06:03) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
You haven't guessed the right amount of times or u won.
>>>
```

This is perfectly fine and expected.

I would modify your program this way:

```
while not (no_of_guesses == 11 or winning_conditon == 1)
```

`while not` would be the equivalent of `until`.