# Running Python code from an IDLE editor window

Tags: python, python-idle

I've programmed a bit in Python for the last few days and everything has worked fine up until yesterday. Whenever I try to run a script now the shell only responds with the message RESTART and a path to where my script is stored. Here's an image:

[image]

I don't know how to fix this and can't find any solutions to it. When I'm writing the code directly into the shell everything works fine but this error only appears when I try to run a script from another file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you cut and paste your output into your question instead of taking a photo of it and posting elsewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title is factually incorrect. The program ran and printed a prompt waiting for new input.  There is no problem to fix except in the questioner's understanding of correct behavior.  Please change the title or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the RESTART line, the behavior you see has nothing to do with IDLE.  Run any program (without IDLE) that does not print anything with the '-i' option and you will see the same thing -- a '>>> ' prompt.

```
C:\Users\Terry>type testprog.py
5+5

C:\Users\Terry>python -i testprog.py
>>> quit()

C:\Users\Terry>
```

IDLE runs a editor window code the same as if it were run in a console (Command Prompt on Windows) with 'python -i'.

Answer (score -1):

That's because your `testprog.py` doesn't actually output anything. Try changing it to `print(5 + 5)` or something similar, currently it only computes `5+5` and then it exits.

Comment: It prints out the result 10 now but above it still says RESTART: C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\testprog.py . Do you know why that is?

Comment: From what I remember of IDLE, it always used to print a big `===== RESTART =====` notice every time I ran a script (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32938433)), but I've never seen it print the path of the script it's running. I assume it's a feature; did you update anything recently?

Comment: Yes, IDLE prints a big `RESTART` message every time it starts running a script. This is to indicate that a new script has started, and it also acts as a separator to output of previous executions. For me, running python 3.4 on linux, it does not print the file path though.

If you run your script from a console (using rather than the IDLE shell/IDE, you won't get this message.

Comment: @Dartmouth If you restart the shell without running a file (see Shell menu), no path is printed. Sometime after 3.4.0, I added the path when a file in the editor *is* run first.  I still need to do so when a file is run on startup.  When one saves the shell output or when one edits and runs multiples files, it helps to identify which output came from which file.